# CentOS 7 system wide display configuration

Tags: centos, display-settings

I have two displays, one connected via DVI and one via HDMI. I installed CentOS 7, which thinks (like every linux I've tried so far), that the one connected via DVI is the primary display and it's on the right side of the one via HDMI.

Unfortunately, it's the other way around: HDMI on the right side, primary screen. DVI on the left side.

Under Settings / Displays I can arrange them. I also managed to set HDMI as primary. But this change is only effective in the current user. (I found that the configuration is saved in ~/.config/monitors.xml)
How can I apply this change to the whole system (including the logon screen and other users)?

Comment: You probably want something along the lines of `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --primary` in an initialization script such as `/etc/X11/Xsession`.

Comment: Probably, yes. But this does not seem to change anything. If I run it from a terminal in a user session, it works fine, though.